# Protractor find element inside a repeater

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Below is my markup

```
<tr ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <td ng-click="activePost(post)" class="title">{{post.title}}</td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete(post)">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to get the element with the `title` class.

The code I use to access the repeater is:

```
postsList = element.all(by.repeater('post in posts'));
```

Is there a way to get the element by doing something like the following in jQuery:

```
var titleText = $("tr:first").find(".title").text();
```

Is there a way of doing something similar to this with protractor?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

this should work for your example:

```
element.all(by.repeater('post in posts')).then(function(posts) {
   var titleElement = posts[0].element(by.className('title'));
   expect(titleElement.getText()).toEqual('YourEnteredTitle');
});
```

Comment: Wasn't able to find it in the documentation. Thank you, that did it.

Comment: Thanks - missing bracket on first line as pointed out by Voles

Comment: I'd be interested to know how this works now that element locators don't return a promise and there for using .then no longer works, do you just do element.all(by.repeater('post in posts))[0].element(by.className('title')); ?

Comment: a little late ... sorry, i cant help you with this. i changed the job (back to C#) and i am not fimiliar with current protractor syntax. if you are still interested to know this, please open a new question.

Answer (score 21):

The answer from [nilsK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2590375/nilsk) helped me, but didn't work completely. The code below did the trick:

```
element.all(by.repeater('post in posts')).then(function(posts) {
   var titleElement = posts[0].element(by.className('title'));
   expect(titleElement.getText()).toEqual('YourEnteredTitle');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

you have to find a element inside a array as explained here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/877

```
var items = element.all(by.repeater('userGroup in userGroups')).filter(function(item) {
     return item.element(by.binding('userGroup.name')).getText().then(function(label) {
           return label === 'MyGroupName';
     });
  });
items.get(0).element(by.css('.buttongochose')).click();
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, because it allow you to filter by text.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md

```
var clickable = element.all(by.repeater('post in posts')).first().all(by.tagName('td')).first();
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for, I mean, it's not the exact chunk of code, but gave me an awesome idea! Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

An even better solution:

`expect(
    $$(by.repeater('post in posts')).get(0).$('.title').getText()
).toBe('Your title');`

Answer (score 0):

More readable way doing the same these days would be

```
it('test case', async () => {
  let repeaters = element.all(by.repeater('post in posts'));
  let titleElement = repeaters.get(0).element(by.className('title'));
  expect(await titleElement.getText()).toEqual('YourEnteredTitle');
});
```