# how to select child element in my test case

Tags: html, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to test a click event for my html

html

```
<div class="testGroup">
    <div ng-repeat="test in tests">
        <a ng-click="clickMe(test.id)">{{test.name}}</a>
        <a ng-click="clickMe(test.id)">{{test.name}}</a>
        <a ng-click="clickMe(test.id)">{{test.name}}</a>
        <a ng-click="clickMe(test.id)">{{test.name}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="testGroup">
    <div ng-repeat="test in tests">
        <a ng-click="clickMe(test.id)">{{test.name}}</a>
        <a ng-click="clickMe(test.id)">{{test.name}}</a>
        <a ng-click="clickMe(test.id)">{{test.name}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="testGroup">
    <div ng-repeat="test in tests">
        <a ng-click="clickMe(test.id)">{{test.name}}</a>
        <a ng-click="clickMe(test.id)">{{test.name}}</a>
        <a ng-click="clickMe(test.id)">{{test.name}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Three divs are identical but I want to select the first testGroup class and click the first a tag. I also want to click the first a tag on the second testGroup class.

In my spec.js

```
element.all(by.css('.testGroup')).get(0).then(function(elem) {
    element(by.repeater('test in tests').row(0)).click();
});
```

I am getting undefined is not a function error. I think it's because the get(0) is not a promise. How do I trigger click on the first a tag in the first testGroup div and first a tag in second testGroup div? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work alright?

```
var testGroupOneTag = $$('.testGroup').get(0).$('[ng-click="clickMe(test.id)"]');
var testGroupTwoTag = $$('.testGroup').get(1).$('[ng-click="clickMe(test.id)"]');
testGroupOneTag.click():
testGroupTwoTag.click():
```

$$ is short for element.all by css.

Comment: It does work. Could you please explain why it works? what does $$ do compare to element.all(by.css('.testGroup')) and what if I want to select second a tag inside the div. + 1

Comment: `$$` selects multiple elements; the same as `element.all`. `get()` is for indexing, thus the example.

Comment: Brine is correct. It is the same as element.all, just the shorthand. A single $ is the same as element(by.css()) and it only grabs the first element that matches. As for multiple tags, I believe you can chain it. For example, if it was 

    <div class="testGroup exampleClass thirdClass">

you could select it by doing 

    $('.testGroup.exampleClass.thirdClass');

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to select the second <a> tag in <a ng-click="clickMe(test.id)">first</a><a ng-click="clickMe(test.id)">second</a>

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but is this what you mean? To click the first ng-click, use `$$('[ng-click="clickMe(test.id)"]').get(0).click()`. To click the second ng-click, use `$$('[ng-click="clickMe(test.id)"]').get(1).click()`. To click the third ng-click, use `$$('[ng-click="clickMe(test.id)"]').get(2).click()`. Please edit the main post with a full size example and then comment to me again if this doesnt answer it.

Comment: Thanks. However, I am getting undefined is not a function error after I put .get(0) after your attribute selector. Also, I have edited the main post.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure... I wouldn't use 'then', as it seems to just work this way for me: `$$('.testGroup').get(0).$('[ng-click="clickMe(test.id)"]').click()`. If it is giving you a problem, maybe this discussion could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757340/protractor-find-element-inside-a-repeater

Answer (score 1):

There is no `then()` on an `ElementFinder` anymore ([since 2.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)).

Chain `element` and `element.all()`, use `by.repeater()` and `column()`:

```
var testGroups = element.all('.testGroup');
var testGroupOneTag = testGroups.first().element(by.repeater("test in tests").column("test.name"));
var testGroupTwoTag = testGroups.get(1).element(by.repeater("test in tests").column("test.name"));

testGroupOneTag.click();
testGroupTwoTag.click();
```