# Find element in parameters of then [protractor]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

Here's my question,

```
element.all(by.repeater('user in users')).then(function(rows) {
// would like to find an element in rows by.css for.exemple
}
```

**EDIT :**

I precise that I'm searching an element using

```
rows[rows.length - 1]
```

and I already tried

```
rows[rows.length - 1].element(by.css('.fa.fa-trash-o')).click();
```

But I got an error

> element is not attached to the page document

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Are you sure that your page is not changing before you click the element `'.fa.fa-trash-o'`? Try waiting until the element is visible using `wait()` function and then probably click on it. Thanks

Comment: refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757340/protractor-find-element-inside-a-repeater

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error usually occurs when the page is dynamically changing and you are trying to access some element that is yet to be visible/loaded. [`wait()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) function can be used to wait until element is loaded before accessing it. Here's how -

```
element.all(by.repeater('user in users')).then(function(rows) {
    var ele = rows[rows.length - 1].element(by.css('.fa.fa-trash-o'));
    browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ele), 10000);
    ele.click();
}
```

Hope it helps.